# Horizontally center div between two floated elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[JSFiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/slynagh/ZewGC/2/).

I'm trying to horizontally center the `div class="filter-group"` in the example between two floated buttons, but failing. Help greatly appreciated.
HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-xs-12 clearfix'>
            <button type='button' class='btn btn-default pull-left'>Previous</button>
            <div class="filter-group">
                Filter projects:
                <button class="btn btn-default">a</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default">b</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default">c</button>
            </div>
            <button type='button' class='btn btn-default pull-right'>Next project</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.filter-group{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: 1px solid #adadad;
    border-right: 1px solid #adadad;
}
    .filter-group button{
    margin: 0 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an update to your code

http://jsfiddle.net/ZewGC/6/

I've made two changes.
Placed both buttons first and then the div, and then removed the `display: inline-block` from the center div.

When you place the floating elements first, the non-floating elements adjust to them, and the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/ZewGC/3/

You could use absolute positioning:

```
display: block;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
-moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
-o-transform: translateX(-50%);
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

Comment: remember to give position: relative; to the parent of this element in order to make it work correctly

Comment: +1 for most creative answer. I'm concerned about wider compatibilty with CSS transforms though.

Comment: You're right. This solution is ie9+, not the best browser support I guess

Answer (score 1):

Just a personal preference, but it seems odd that you are using a grid system without using the grid system to position your elements.  So, I would recommend using your cols to center...e.g.

```
<div class='col-xs-2'>Left Button here</div>
<div class='col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2'>Centered block</div>
<div class='col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-2'>Right button here</div>
```

Comment: True, that would be quite sensible.